# Move elements with specific values to bottom of sorted array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that I want to sort by specific values, f.x. price. The objects have an item called `"status"` that can have either `"available", "reserved" or "occupied"`.
The sorting on f.x price works perfectly fine, but what I am trying to achieve is to take the sorted array and take out the items that have a status other than `"available"` and put them to the bottom of the array, with `"reserved"` before `"occupied"`, but also sorted by their price.

So when I have a random sorted array

```
[{
    id: 1619,
    address: "Street 1",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 10695, 
    status: "Available",
},
{
    id: 1620,
    address: "Street 5",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 7859, 
    status: "Available",
},
{
    id: 1626,
    address: "Street 7",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 8595, 
    status: "Reserved",
},
{
    id: 1624,
    address: "Street 11",
    rooms: 4,
    price: 9795, 
    status: "Occupied",
},
{
    id: 1624,
    address: "Street 3",
    rooms: 4,
    price: 2856, 
    status: "Reserved",
}]
```

and use

```
function sortList(property, list, order) {
        list.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a[property] === b[property]) {
                return 0;
            }
            const va = a[property];
            const vb = b[property];

            if (order === 'asc') {
                return va < vb ? 1 : -1;
            }
            return va > vb ? 1 : -1;
        });
    }

    sortList("price", list, "desc");
```

to sort it by price - this works fine. I then want to take that sorted list and put "Reserved" and "Occupied" to the bottom of the array - still sorted by price, so I end up with an array like this:

```
[{
    id: 1620,
    address: "Street 5",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 7859, 
    status: "Available",
},
{
    id: 1619,
    address: "Street 1",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 10695, 
    status: "Available",
},
{
    id: 1624,
    address: "Street 3",
    rooms: 4,
    price: 2856, 
    status: "Reserved",
},
{
    id: 1626,
    address: "Street 7",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 8595, 
    status: "Reserved",
},
{
    id: 1624,
    address: "Street 11",
    rooms: 4,
    price: 9795, 
    status: "Occupied",
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out the items you want, remove them from the list and then push them to the end of the list (after sorting).

```js
const list = [{
    id: 1619,
    address: "Street 1",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 10695,
    status: "Available",
  },
  {
    id: 1620,
    address: "Street 5",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 7859,
    status: "Available",
  },
  {
    id: 1626,
    address: "Street 7",
    rooms: 3,
    price: 8595,
    status: "Reserved",
  },
  {
    id: 1624,
    address: "Street 11",
    rooms: 4,
    price: 9795,
    status: "Occupied",
  },
  {
    id: 1624,
    address: "Street 3",
    rooms: 4,
    price: 2856,
    status: "Reserved",
  }
];

function sortList(property, list, order) {
  list.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[property] === b[property]) {
      return 0;
    }
    const va = a[property];
    const vb = b[property];

    if (order === 'asc') {
      return va < vb ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return va > vb ? 1 : -1;
  });
}

function extractItems(list) {
  const extracted = list.filter(el => el.status == "Reserved" || el.status == "Occupied");
  
  list = list.filter((el) => !extracted.includes(el));
  
  list.push(extracted);
  
  return list;
}

sortList("price", list, "desc");
newList = extractItems(list)

console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array's sort function (list is your original array):

```
const l = list.sort( (a,b) => {
    if(a.status === b.status) return a.price - b.price;

    const x = a.status === "Available" ? 0 : a.status === "Reserved" ? 1 : 2;
    const y = b.status === "Available" ? 0 : b.status === "Reserved" ? 1 : 2;
    return x-y;
 });

console.log(l);
```

Function just compares price if status is the same otherwise it compares statuses.